# Simulating "line of sight" with obstacles on 2d grid?

Tags: 2d, grid, line-of-sight

Ran into an interesting problem. I need to figure out how to simulate line of sight - simple enough, just on a 2d grid with obstacles. Either a grid cell is visible, or it's not.

I can get something really rudimentary going - like spreading n spaces from player, or blocking horizontal propagation when an adjacent obstacle is detected, but I can't let myself live with it. Plenty of other apps are using more sophisticated methods that slope the line of sight around corners etc, and I want to be up to par.

So far DCSS has been my source of inspiration when I'm stumped, I'm hoping to get something close to what they have: http://crawl.s-z.org/.

Any insight would be appreciated - thanks for the help!

(Forgive if this is embarassingly noobish - only started game dev a few weeks ago, trying hard to catch up.)

Comment: When you say "slope the line of sight around corners", what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Best I can say is to check out a game on crawl.s-z.org. As an example, when the player is standing below a horizontal wall 5 tiles wide, the line of sight breaks above the horizontal plane of that wall - but not unrealistically beyond it. The best I've been able to approximate is keeping the line of sight at the horizontal plane of the wall.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Ray casting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_casting) is a very fast and efficient way to determine line-of-sight. It basically involves sending a ray (think of it like an infinite laser that can't be redirected) from a certain position in a certain direction. Using this ray, you can determine things like which point(s) it intersects and how far away from the origin it was when it crossed a certain point.

So for example, in a player/enemy scenario, the ray could originate from the enemy with the direction being the location of the player. If the ray collides with a solid tile, the enemy can't see the player. If it doesn't, the enemy can see the player.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15604/Ray-casting-in-a-2D-tile-based-environment) is an excellent tutorial that will should help.

You can also consider [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) (summed up, it creates lines) for something that might be more easily scaled to tiles.

Comment: Seems like the way to go - especially bresenham's. Thanks for the help djent!

Answer (score 3):

I have [blogged code](http://williamedwardscoder.tumblr.com/post/13269950091/a-while-ago-i-was-playing-with-computing) to compute line of sight from a height-map.  A simple flat map with obstacles is just a very flat height-map, and this implementation is still completely applicable.

[image]

Here it is in C++ and its `O(n)`; if you know the maximum height in the map, you can track a scanline that has no rays remaining under that height, and early-out:

```
typedef std::vector<float> visbuf_t;

inline void map::_visibility_scan(const visbuf_t& in,visbuf_t& out,const vec_t& eye,int start_x,int stop_x,int y,int prev_y) {
    const int xdir = (start_x < stop_x)? 1: -1;
    for(int x=start_x; x!=stop_x; x+=xdir) {
        const int x_diff = abs(eye.x-x), y_diff = abs(eye.z-y);
        const bool horiz = (x_diff >= y_diff);
        const int x_step = horiz? 1: x_diff/y_diff;
        const int in_x = x-x_step*xdir; // where in the in buffer would we get the inner value?
        const float outer_d = vec2_t(x,y).distance(vec2_t(eye.x,eye.z));
        const float inner_d = vec2_t(in_x,horiz? y: prev_y).distance(vec2_t(eye.x,eye.z));
        const float inner = (horiz? out: in).at(in_x)*(outer_d/inner_d); // get the inner value, scaling by distance
        const float outer = height_at(x,y)-eye.y; // height we are at right now in the map, eye-relative
        if(inner <= outer) {
            out.at(x) = outer;
            vis.at(y*width+x) = VISIBLE;
        } else {
            out.at(x) = inner;
            vis.at(y*width+x) = NOT_VISIBLE;
        }
    }
}

void map::visibility_add(const vec_t& eye) {
    const float BASE = -10000; // represents a downward vector that would always be visible
    visbuf_t scan_0, scan_out, scan_in;
    scan_0.resize(width);
    vis[eye.z*width+eye.x-1] = vis[eye.z*width+eye.x] = vis[eye.z*width+eye.x+1] = VISIBLE;
    scan_0.at(eye.x) = BASE;
    scan_0.at(eye.x-1) = BASE;
    scan_0.at(eye.x+1) = BASE;
    _visibility_scan(scan_0,scan_0,eye,eye.x+2,width,eye.z,eye.z);
    _visibility_scan(scan_0,scan_0,eye,eye.x-2,-1,eye.z,eye.z);
    scan_out = scan_0;
    for(int y=eye.z+1; y<height; y++) {
        scan_in = scan_out;
        _visibility_scan(scan_in,scan_out,eye,eye.x,-1,y,y-1);
        _visibility_scan(scan_in,scan_out,eye,eye.x,width,y,y-1);
    }
    scan_out = scan_0;
    for(int y=eye.z-1; y>=0; y--) {
        scan_in = scan_out;
        _visibility_scan(scan_in,scan_out,eye,eye.x,-1,y,y+1);
        _visibility_scan(scan_in,scan_out,eye,eye.x,width,y,y+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good, but I think far more than he's after if what he wants is anything like the link he posted.

Comment: Very in-depth and impressive, but djent is right - way out of my scope. Thanks for the post though!

Comment: @CodeMoose eh its working code; just cut-n-paste, translate literally to whatever language you're targeting.  It is an implementation of Bresenham, done incrementally so it only visits each square once.  If you, for each grid square, do a Bresenham line to the player, you'll find it massively slower.

Comment: Good point will