# Fast Occlusion Discovery in 3D Point Cloud

Tags: c++, voxels, octree, occlusion, point-cloud

I am trying to find occluded objects given a view point at `x,y,z` in the scene. For instance in the example below all the points constructing trees should be returned as occluded objects (because of the building).
[image: octree]

Is there any better approach than tracing rays and querying occupancy of every voxel on those rays within the Octree? This approach doesn't look efficient as the complexity significantly grows with number of voxels and distance from `P(x,y,z)` in the scene.

Comment: If your occluders are reasonably large/dense, then an approach like [Minecraft's Advanced Cave Culling Algorithm](https://tomcc.github.io/2014/08/31/visibility-1.html) might be suitable. There's also a [2D algorithm described here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/47576/39518) that you may be able to extend to a 3D analog, or apply to 2D slices if your occluders tend to be tall like these.